Rails project: Text input not redirecting to preview page despite troubleshooting
I'm encountering an issue with a Rails project I've been working on locally. I've set up two pages using generate formatting input preview: an input page and a preview page. The idea is simple: I input text on the input page, and upon clicking the "Preview" button, the text should be displayed on the preview page.
However, despite spending hours troubleshooting and seeking assistance from various sources, including talking with ChatGPT3 for hours, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.
When I type text on the input page and click the "Preview" button, the page refreshes, but I'm not redirected to the preview page where the typed text should be displayed. Instead, I remain on the input page.
I've ensured that my routes are correctly defined, and I've tried various adjustments in the controller actions to handle the form submission and redirection properly, but to no avail.
I'm seeking further guidance and assistance on how to troubleshoot and fix this stubborn issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Here's what my code looks like in each of the main files;
Routes:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/formatting/input', to: 'formatting#input'
  post '/formatting/preview', to: 'formatting#preview'
  root 'formatting#input'
end

Preview:
 <h1>Preview</h1>
 <p><%= simple_format(@input_text) %></p>

Input:
<%= form_with url: 'preview', method: :post do %>
  <%= text_area_tag 'input_text' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Preview' %>
<% end %>

Formatting_controller:
class FormattingController < ApplicationController
  def input
  end
 def preview 
      @input_text = params[:input_text]
      render 'preview'
  end
end

Thank you in advance!

You can use <%= form_with url: 'preview' do %> or <%= form_tag('preview') do %>
But I prefer to use get endpoint for preview and <%= form_with url: 'preview', method: :get do %>

I've tested all three variants. With the first two, the issue remains mostly unchanged; the input page doesn't even refresh when I type text and click the button. The third variant still fails to redirect to the preview page where the inputted text should be displayed. Initially, it showed that the preview didn't have a GET route. Consequently, I added a GET route for preview in the routes configuration. After this adjustment, the server now responds with the following log: https://i.imgur.com/oR2PoBp.png

Based on what you provided in the screenshot "/formatting/preview" is redirecting to "/formatting/input" this is not shown in your code. Please double check your code as well as update the post with your findings (including logs as needed Not Screenshots)
